# Overlay PNG/JPG RGB images on density plot of image entropy

Tags: r, python-3.x, visualization, data-analysis, probability-density

I have a large number of images and I want to plot a density plot of the entropy of each image. I would like to then overlay the individual images on top of the density plot, does anyone have any advice on what would be the best package or program to do this? I generally work with Python-3 and R but would consider others if easier/better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an R option using the function `sinkr::addImg()`. You can add an image to an existing plot by specifying the x and y coordinates for the image center as well as the desired width (in x-axis units):

```
library(sinkr) # https://github.com/marchtaylor/sinkr
library(png)

myurl <- paste0("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/", 
  "e/e1/Jupiter_%28transparent%29.png/242px-Jupiter_%28transparent%29.png")
z <- tempfile()
download.file(myurl,z,mode="wb")
pic <- readPNG(z)
file.remove(z) # cleanup
dim(pic)

image(volcano)
addImg(pic, x = 0.3, y = 0.5, width = 0.4)
addImg(pic, x = 0.4, y = 0.6, width = 0.1)
```

[image]